# ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 54003 not found in EPSG support files. Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, epsg

I often get this error message when running pyqgis scripts on QGS project in EPSG:54003 or 54004 (I also noticed also some other SRSs in the past):

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 54003 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?
```

Indeed, EPSG:54003 is implemented in QGIS (v2.18) by default and I can normally work in the QGIS desktop in this SRS.

Sometimes the script goes through, sometimes it stops.

What is the reason for the error message?
Where are the *EPSG support files* located?

Comment: You may find code 54003 in C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal\esri_extra.wkt, C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj\esri and C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj\esri_extra. Note that GDAL expects EPSG:54003, while PROJ.4 expects ESRI:54003 to be invoked.

Comment: Can you give a reproducable workflow for that error?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where the EPSG support files are located but I can answer your other questions.

The [EPSG registry](https://www.epsg-registry.org) / EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset uses well-known IDs between 1 and 32766. Any number larger than that, including 900913, has been defined be another "authority". The codes, 54003 and 54004, could be from Esri.

54003 is a Miller Cylindrical projection using WGS84. 54004 is "World Mercator" also using WGS84 and is functionally the same as EPSG's 3395.

GDAL/PROJ.4 have a set of look-up table for Esri-defined coordinate reference systems but the last time I looked they were very out-of-date.

Disclosure: I work at Esri and I'm a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.

Comment: What prevents Miller Cylindrical and similar ESRI projections to get into the main EPSG database (with a new number below 32766)?

Comment: General idea is that the registry is for crs that's either been in use or is in use. The projections that are designed for showing the entire world are more one-offs that are often customized with different central meridians.

Comment: @mkennedy, isn't it a strange reasoning that "often" customized projections cannot get epsg below 32766. I often customize Azimuthal Equal Area projections (e.g. Lambert, epsg 3571, 3572, etc). Shouldn't I?