# ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 102027 not found in EPSG support files

Tags: python, epsg, psycopg2, pygdal

I am trying to insert spatial data from GeoJSON to PostgreSQL database and before it I am to reproject geom from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:102027. When working on Windows there were no problems with CRS, but now I get in Python

> ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 102027 not found in EPSG support files.  Is
>   this a valid EPSG coordinate system? ERROR 6: No translation for an
>   empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known.

Probably the error connected with:

- That I moved to Ubuntu and maybe I missed some packages?
- The venv (on Windows I didn't use it)

I have installed pygdal 2.2.2.3 package, GDAL 2.2.2

in database I have POSTGIS=2.1.8

> EPSG:102027 is an 'Asia_North_Lambert_Conformal_Conic' projection with
>   description (I have it in QGIS!) +proj=lcc +lat_1=15 +lat_2=65
>   +lat_0=30 +lon_0=95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

I found [the same problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256746/error-6-epsg-pcs-gcs-code-54003-not-found-in-epsg-support-files-is-this-a-vali) but no solution, [this issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293537/how-to-update-the-epsg-database-of-gdal-on-ubuntu) offers to update EPSG database - I already have GDAL 2.2.2...

Strangely, I really haven't srid = 102027 in spatial_ref_sys table!

I am puzzled, maybe any ideas?

Comment: 102027 is not an EPSG code http://epsg-registry.org/ but something from ESRI and therefore not available in PostGIS by default. You should be able to add the definitions into your PostGIS with the command that you''ll find from http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102027/postgis/.

Comment: @user30184, it doesn't help(

Comment: How about using `-s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=15 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"`?

Comment: huh, yep, this is now my working version)) but I still wondering if I could call it as ImportFromEPSG(102027). This worked before!